# Custom copy, paste and delete in java using JTextArea

Tags: java, swing, copy, clipboard, paste

I have an arraylist of some object `ArrayList<Object_Name>` which I want to use it as a custom clipboard. Is there a way where I can cut, copy, paste and delete the strings that I enter in the `JTextArea` making use of this custom clipboard?

Comment: Please give an example of what you have done so far so that it is easy to help you.

Comment: You may find [Making cut/replace methods with JTextArea](http://stackoverflow.com/q/544740/1048330) useful.